# UPDATE query in ACCESS with AVERAGE value from other table

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have these two simple access tables.

`Table 1` consists of an Item `description` and `weight` column. Item `description` is not unique as `weight` slightly varies.

`Table 2` is designed to hold the average `weight` of the items in `table 1`. In this table the item `description` is unique.

I cannot make the UPDATE query in ACCESS work. It says the query does not include `weight` as part of an aggregate function.

When I attempt to add a GROUP BY clause, it still does not work due to syntax errors..

Anyone have an idea as to what might be the issue?

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE TABLE2 
INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.DESCRIPTION = TABLE1.DESCRIPTION
SET TABLE2.WEIGHT = AVG(TABLE1.WEIGHT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.WEIGHT = t1.AVG_WEIGHT 
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN (select  TABLE1.DESCRIPTION,AVG(TABLE1.WEIGHT) as AVG_WEIGHT
   from TABLE1 
  group by TABLE1.DESCRIPTION) as t1
on TABLE2.DESCRIPTION = TABLE1.DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: @BarrievanBoven it seems that this is T-SQL syntax not Jet-SQL

Comment: @4dmonster -yes this is not possible in ms acess

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler way here-

You need to create a staging or inter-mediate table to calculate the average.

You must create a new table t3,from query-

```
select TABLE1.DESCRIPTION,AVG(TABLE1.WEIGHT) as AVG_WEIGHT    
from TABLE1 
group by TABLE1.DESCRIPTION
```

And then you can use it in update query

```
  UPDATE TABLE2 
    INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.DESCRIPTION = TABLE2.DESCRIPTION
    SET TABLE3.WEIGHT = TABLE2.WEIGHT
```

Comment: yes ok, this works of course.. Was just wondering why i could not fix it in 1 query. It seems simple enough